# Не срабатывает событие

Tags: c#, winforms

Не срабатывает событие на клик по кнопке(Она существует, все название совпадают)
Что делать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Привет");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В редакторе форм выделите кнопку, и посмотрите в окне свойств на за закладке eventov, что там висит на button1_click

Comment: У автосгенерированного обработчика события слово `Click` было бы с большой буквы (а в новых версиях Студии и `Button`, и `TextBox` тоже с большой). Так что вы явно вручную что-то где-то поменяли.

Comment: `Она существует, все название совпадают` — код лучше тысячи слов, покажите код, в котором создается кнопка и идет привязка обработчика к событию.

Answer (score 1):

Привяжите обработчик к событию в коде "вручную", заодно и научитесь это делать, добавьте в конструктор:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += button1_click; // Эту строчку
}
```